# Get the .NET framework version from a process dump

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know the CLR version of a crash dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673542/how-can-i-know-the-clr-version-of-a-crash-dump)

If I open a dump file (of a managed process) in WinDbg, is there anyway of finding which version of .NET framework that process was using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lm (List Modules) command can provide such information, with verbose output and the Match flag:

```
lmv m mscor*
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a guess, but if you can check what modules were loaded, you should see what version of mscorwks.dll (.NET 2.0 / 3.5) or clr.dll (.NET 4.0) was used.

You can use 'lmv' command.